# Finding the height of an irregular cylinder?

Tags: calculus

I need to find the height of an irregular cylinder. Its difficult due to both diameters being different.

Here are the Details

Capacity: 250 Ml
Bottom Diameter: 4.8 cm 
Top Diameter 8 cm

Please help.

Comment: What is that unit on capacity?

Comment: The unit of the capacity is mL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are given a truncated cone with $r_1 = 0.048 \text{ m}$, $r_2 = 0.08 \text{ m}$, and volume $V = 0.00025 \text{ m}^3$.

$$ V = \frac{1}{3} \pi h (r_1^2 + r_1 r_2 + r_2^2) $$
So you can plug in your values and solve for $h$ where
$$ h = \frac{3 V}{\pi (r_1^2 + r_1 r_2 + r_2^2)} = 0.0190 \text{ m} = 1.9 \text{ cm}$$

Comment: am i able to do this with units other then m?

Comment: Sure, you can do it with any units you want.  For example, you could have kept it cm all along, but then you would want your volume also in cubic cm.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you describing a [conical frustrum](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicalFrustum.html)?  It is a cone with a cone cut off, similar to a trapezoid?  If the height is $h$ and the radii are $r_1,r_2$, $$V=\frac 13\pi h(r_1^2+r_1r_2+r_2^2)$$

Comment: Im quite sure how to set it out.

Comment: You have the two radii and the volume.  How do millilitres relate to centimeters?

Comment: i mean *not* apologies

Comment: With every cm theres 10 mm? im not sure

Comment: Note that millilitres are volume and centimeters are length.  You need to cube length to get volume.  You could see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litre) on the litre

Comment: @RossMillikan, I believe you are missing a factor or $\pi$ on the rhs.

Comment: @Jedediyah:  Fixed.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help.